# Не работает удаление через ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server

В коде есть следующий участок:

```
using(var deleteConnection = new SqlConnection(connectString))
{
    deleteConnection.Open();
    var deleteCmd = deleteConnection.CreateCommand();
    deleteCmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [tableName] WHERE [id] IN (1,2,3,...,1000)";
    deleteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

на команде `ExecuteNonQuery` выполнение прерывается, через 30 секунд, получаю ошибку `timeout expired`, при этом, если запрос выполнить через SSMS, нормально выполняется за 3 секунды.

Comment: Sql профайлером смотрели, что происходит?

Comment: У Вас случайно нет открытого курсора на ту же таблицу в этот момент?

Comment: Удаление происходит после копирования через `SqlBulkCopy` (по событию `SqlRowsCopied`)

Comment: @tym32167 при обработке из приложения: `SQL:BatchStarting <query>` из SSMS: `SQL:BatchStarting <query> SQL:BatchCompleted <query>`

Comment: @qzavyer блок IN плохо работает с 1000 и более значениями, перепишите свой DELETE на DELETE c JOIN и все взлетит.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, пробовал изменить код, чтобы в `IN` было 2 значения, результат тот же

Comment: @qzavyer тогда троссируйте, ваша таблица явно занята.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, во время копирования с помощью `SqlBulkCopy` в ActiveMonitor отображаются события `SELECT` и `INSERT` при попытке удаления событие `DELETE` оказывается заблокированным селектом, при этом, если подключиться к другой базе, всё работает. Индексы в обеих базах одинаковые, триггеров нет